# multiple java versions on WebLogic

Tags: java, weblogic

Is it possible to run multiple versions of Java on WebLogic 10.3.6 and/or 12c?
We have applications that use different versions of Java. For example, is it possible to use JRE6 and JRE7 at the same time for different applications?

Comment: If you are using different managed servers on different machines and a node-manager, could you try changing the JVM on each server as per http://xmlandmore.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/configuring-weblogic-server-with.html and seeing if it works. Stephen C is probably right though - what do you expect not to work in either 6 or 7?

Comment: Actually - you can also set JAVA_HOME/CLASSPATH/etc on the WebLogic Console under Environment -> Servers -> [Server Name] -> Configuration -> Server Start too. That's probably easier to try and may work if both managed servers are on the same machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have different instances of Weblogic running at the same time, then I can't see how this would be possible.  A JVM instance (running a Weblogic instance) runs one and only one version of Java.

However, I expect you will find that an application that is implemented for Java 6 will run just fine using a Java 7 JRE.

Answer (score 2):

The answers above make the good point that you shouldn't NEED to run different JVMs for Java6 or Java7.

If there is some valid reason why this doesn't apply, the WebLogic console allows you to specify different JVM settings for each server.

Go to:

```
 Environment -> Servers -> [Server Name] -> Configuration -> Server Start
```

and specify the Java Home, Classpath, Arguments, etc.

I have not ever tested this with different versions on the same machine, so please test before committing yourself to your business :-)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to **use the highest required Java version** (JVM7 in the current situation). There is backward compatibility, and I can hardly imagine that a Java6 application would not run on Java7.

Also, it reduces the operational costs (much easier to setup, to to maintain, to update patches, etc.) - you just don't have to worry about it.