# Is it possible to deploy multiple applications of different Java versions in the Weblogic Application Server?

Tags: java, weblogic, compatibility

I saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14476902/multiple-java-versions-on-weblogic) here on SO but the answers only refer to Java 1.6 and Java 1.7. I have an application that uses Java 1.4, would it be possible to deploy it on Weblogic?

Comment: Java is supposed to be backwards-compatible. Are you sure your application won't just run under the latest JVM (even if it was developed for 1.4)?

Comment: I'm not actually in charge of doing the deployment to Weblogic, they are insisting we should upgrade the code and recompile it to 1.6. I saw [this question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10895969/can-newer-jre-version-run-java-programs-compiled-with-older-jdk-versions) that indeed says Java should be backward compatible, meaning that no matter how old my compiled application is, it should still run on higher Java versions.

Comment: To add, I'm using Tomcat for development which utilizes Java 1.6, so I don't really know how they come up with the need for me to upgrade the application to 1.6 when it runs on Tomcat perfectly using Java 1.4 compiled code.

Comment: what version of weblogic? if your app works on Tomcat with jdk 1.6 then it should work with weblogic that supports jdk 1.6 as well

Comment: The version of Weblogic is 11g, would you happen to know if that runs on Java 1.6?

Comment: Yes Weblogic 11g can run with Java 1.6. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/doc.1111/e14142/installer_list.htm

Comment: Thank you, so there's no reason my app shouldn't run with 1.4 compiled classes on Weblogic 11g which runs 1.6. Thank you everyone.